# Git status after renaming parent directory

Tags: git, directory, rename

When a parent directory was renamed, all its files will be shown in git status as renamed. Is there any way to detect the parent directory was renamed but not its files programmatically?

For example. I have following directory and files in a git repository.

```
AParent\ADirectory\file1
AParent\ADirectory\file2
```

When i rename the directory AParent to AParent-Renamed, the git status is as following.

```
renamed AParent\ADirectory\file1 -> AParent-Renamed\ADirectory\file1
renamed AParent\ADirectory\file2 -> AParent-Renamed\ADirectory\file2
```

Is there any way to find out that only the ADirectory was renamed? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directories, on their own, aren't tracked - files are. As far as git is concerned, the only interesting change here is that a bunch of files have been moved to another (new, in this case), directory.

So, to answer the question - in a word, no.